# What type of server is using Django/Python? .htaccess is compatible?

Tags: htaccess, server, django, python

I was wondering what type of server is using python & django because i don't know if can i use an *.htaccess* file and if there is something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python and Django can run on Apache so you can use an .htaccess file on that setup.  It also runs on [several other server setups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29#Server_arrangements) which have support for .htaccess-like functions.

In short, you're good...go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is the one who uses .htaccess files. It is a modular server with many default modules plus ones you can install yourself.

If you want to use Python then you need the [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) module. Depending on your installation, it may be there or not as a default module.

Django is a framework which depends on Python and a database which is often MySQL but can be Postgres or Oracle according to the [installation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/install/#set-up-a-database).